# Navigation from a filtered list to default view?

Tags: usability, website-design, navigation, filter

Suppose I am designing a web site to display a list of items. I'd like to add a category filter to display only the items of a given category.

Now I'm wondering how user should *move back* from the filtered list to the default list of items. Should I add just a "home" link or button ? Should I use "bread crumbs" with a "home" link ? What would you suggest ?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Could there be many filters? Does a user need to select extra filters after applying a filter?

Comment: You can think about a local tech meetup web site. The default view is just a list of recent meetups. You can also filter the meetups by technology (e.g. web-programming meetups), by date (e.g. all meetups this month), etc.

Comment: I don't think I need to apply more than one filter at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need more information to answer this, but:

If this is an ad hoc filter:
The filter could just be cleared to return to the original list. And since a filtered list should be the same page as the unfiltered list, no navigation would be needed.

Comment: Thanks. I see your point. Now i know that I'm asking about _navigation_ :) (changed the question title)

Comment: Do you have any examples of such web sites ?

Comment: Typical e-commerce site filters can be seen at cars.com or amazon.com (these have left sidebar filters). 

If you are looking at an operations platform like Jira or Salesforce, these utilize query based filters that a user can type in a search box. 

Those are the primary methods I've seen. It sounds like your project would benefit more from the e-commerce method. Checkout cars.com:
https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?rd=20&searchSource=QUICK_FORM&zc=84043